# C# Access Of Public Method Between Forms

Tags: c#, forms, methods, public

I'm trying to do a simple project for my module.  I made a login system for my program and the idea is the menustrip controls are disabled until the user puts in the correct details and submits it. So far this is what I came up with and is in the main form:

```
    public void setControlDisabled()
    {
        fileToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        clientsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        dVDsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        windowsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void setControlEnabled()
    {
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        this.clientsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        this.dVDsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        this.windowsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
```

And the following code is in my login form amongst other code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //other code
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.setControlEnabled();
}
```

The disable part works fine, even if I put a little MessageBox in the setControlEnabled method it shows, but it doesn't enable the menustrip.

PS. Login on the menustrip is still enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because you need to store the reference to form and use that. Don't recreate the form or else you are talking to a different instance, which will have its items enabled. if you call `form.Show()` in your current code, you will see this

Here is how you can deal with this:

```
Form1 otherForm;
Form1 OtherForm
{
    get
    { 
         //If the form is requested but not created yet, create it
         if(otherForm == null) 
             otherForm = new Form1();
         return otherForm;
    }
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //other code
            OtherForm.setControlEnabled();
}
```

The property lazily handles the creation of the form. If it was already created, then it just returns that instance, otherwise it creates a new instance and returns that. It will hold onto this reference, though. So you will need to have a clear method or a setter so that you can set it to null if it is closed and you want it removed fully.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your Form1 instance is locally scoped to your btnLogin_Click method, rather than being a global instance.  Declare your Form1 instance within the Class declaration, Ie:

```
public class Form2
    private Form1 form = new Form1();

    public Form2()
    {
        form.Show();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.setControlEnabled();
    }
}
```